# Node.js Illegal instruction: 4

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a server that uses Socket.IO to send binary data to the server and vice versa. Recently I have been getting these errors, and the worst part is that I don't know where to start my debugging. This seems like an internal error.

```
#
# Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/handles.h, line 48
# CHECK(location_ != NULL) failed
#

==== C stack trace ===============================

1: ??
2: ??
3: ??
4: ??
5: ??
6: ??
Illegal instruction: 4
```

I'm using Node v0.11.16.
Any help??

Comment: You should try a stable version of node, such as node v0.12.x.